# Verbose suspend mode?

Tags: logs, power-management, suspend

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 on my ThinkBook 13s-IWL.

When I close the lid or go to the suspend mode manually, the laptop seems to crash most of the time.

That means, the display turns black as expected, the power button is still shining for a while, and then, when it should normally go into a blinking mode, it just turns completely off instead. Resulting in a loss of my previous session and all unsaved settings.

How can I get more information from my system about what happened?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably your laptop will activate systemd-suspend, so having a look into that should be helpful, including the systemd log facilities. Arch has some good info about their systemd-suspend version, which may also be helpful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management#Power_management_with_systemd

Comment: Even if this is not the answer to be question above: It seems to work now by disabling the hybrid sleep mode via "sudo systemctl mask hybrid-sleep.target". I don't know where the problem is, but in Windows it was solved by setting the option "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\CsEnabled -> 0" which is the "connected standby" feature.

Hope this solution will last...

Comment: If your laptop was going to `hybrid-sleep` on lid close, maybe try to replace the setting with `hibernate` or `suspend` instead. At least on my laptop latter two work, but hybrid does not either.